# Python - Local variable referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, opencv3.0, faster-rcnn

I am trying to adopt mask_rcnn original code to my dataset.The original code takes xml files and I just modified my code to accept json format. Here is the code

```py
   def load_mask(self, image_id, xml=False):
        # get details of image
        info = self.image_info[image_id]

        if xml:
            # define anntation  file location
            path = info['annotation']
            # load XML
            boxes, w, h = self.extract_boxes(path, xml=True)
        else:
            with open('D:\Mask_RCNN\Mask_RCNN\dataset\\annots\\annotations.json', 'r') as f:
                annots = json.load(f)
                found = False
                for value in annots.values():
                    if 'image' in value and value['instance_list']:
                        if value['image']['original_filename'][:-3] == info['id']:
                            boxes, w, h = self.extract_boxes(value)
                            found = True
                            break

        if found:
            # create one array for all masks, each on a different channel
            masks = zeros([h, w, len(boxes)], dtype='uint8')
        else:
            stop = "here"

                if found:
            # create one array for all masks, each on a different channel
            masks = zeros([h, w, len(boxes)], dtype='uint8')
        else:
            stop = "here"

        # create masks
        class_ids = list()
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            box = boxes[i]
            row_s, row_e = box[1], box[3]
            col_s, col_e = box[0], box[2]
            masks[row_s:row_e, col_s:col_e, i] = 1
            class_ids.append(self.class_names.index('Penquins'))
        return masks, asarray(class_ids, dtype='int32')

    # load an image reference
        #"""Return the path of the image."""
    def image_reference(self, image_id):
            info = self.image_info[image_id]
            print(info)
            return info['path']
```

It gives me the error

> File "C:/PycharmProjects/Mask_RCNN/Mask_RCNN/objects.py", line 197, in load_mask
>               for i in range(len(boxes)):
>           UnboundLocalError: local variable 'boxes' referenced before assignment

I tried to debug the code,its throwing an error before creating masks but I am not able to figure out whats wrong.  Any idea?

Comment: Where did you declare `boxes`?

Comment: @Guy: *Declare* should read: *assign to* or *initialize*.

Comment: @guidot "Starting with Python 3.6, you can declare types of variables and functions"  https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @guy I think he meant there is no such thing as declaring in python. However as told in my other comment, there is.

Comment: @guy, sorry i posted again with few more lines of code

Comment: If the error is *referenced before assignment* it means, that the variable has not yet got a value and not the the interpreter does not know about it.

Comment: In your function definition write this statement      boxes = None   as your first line.

Comment: @Wimanicesir type-hints are not variable declarations. Python doesn't *have variable declarations*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, read the docs.. They even use "declare" multiple times in the docs themself. A definition found somewhere else is "The declaration gives a name and a data type for the variable."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Also this -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-definition-and-declaration/

Comment: @Wimanicesir while you are technically correct, might I suggest stopping this discussion here? It is entirely off topic and probably serves to only confuse the original poster

Answer (score 0):

Only if `xml` is true, it is guaranteed, that boxes gets a value. Otherwise additional conditions have to be fulfilled, which does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

`boxes` is initialized in *some* of the scenarios in `load_mask`'s first `if else` block, which means it might not exists when you reach `if found:`. Just declare it in the beginning

```
def load_mask(self, image_id, xml=False):
    # get details of image
    info = self.image_info[image_id]
    boxes = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to iterate over the number of `boxes`, but your if statements above are constructed in such a way that `boxes` might not exit by the time this statement gets executed.

try this simple example:

```
user_input = "no"

if user_input =="yes":
    boxes = [1,2,3,4]
else:
    pass

print(boxes)
```

This will result in the same error as you are seeing. Your problem is that both of these if statements must pass before `boxes` is defined:

```
           if 'image' in value and value['instance_list']:
                if value['image']['original_filename'][:-3] == info['id']:
```

Likely you either need additional logic that ensures the iteration only occurs if certain conditions are met. Or, if `boxes` is a list you could start your code by defining `boxes=[]`. In that case the iteration will simply pass over without doing anything as the length of `boxes` is zero in that case

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that boxes isnt getting declared in line of this for loop, so define boxes as an empty list in the first part of the function

```
def load_mask(self, image_id, xml=False):
    boxes = []
    #do all the other stuff here
```

Then when you do the for loop it should now be declared (unless one of the functions don't return the boxes and give you something else)

Quick tip when doing the for loop, you can do

```
for i, box in enumerate(boxes):
    ...
```

which will not make you define box inside the loop (i will be 0 to len(boxes)-1 and box will be the box with that index)